# Cassandra write by UUID for conflict resolution

Tags: java, cassandra, nosql, distributed-system

In the "[Designing Data-Intensive Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449373321)" chapter 5 (Section # "Last write wins (discarding concurrent writes)") book the author says:

> The only safe way of using a database with LWW is to ensure that a key
> is only written once and thereafter treated as immutable, thus
> avoiding any concurrent updates to the same key. For example, a
> recommended way of using Cassandra is to use a UUID as the key, thus
> giving each write operation a unique key [[53]](https://www.datastax.com/blog/why-cassandra-doesnt-need-vector-clocks).

My question is what does the author mean here by saying use UUID as the key for every write? Even if you use UUID as a key for the table you are ultimately using that uuid to update some columns after you are done with insertion, isn't it? May be he means something else so could someone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't look right to me. It isn't necessary to use UUIDs as the key.

In most cases, natural keys are preferred. For example: email addresses, movie title + release year, user IDs, etc.

In Cassandra, all mutations (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`) get persisted but the last write wins. Cassandra uses the latest write timestamp to determine which version is the latest. Cheers!